# What idiom is equivalent to "They cover themselves with the same blanket"?

Tags: modismos

I’m looking for a Hispanic idiom. My pastor used to mention it as being equivalent to "Birds of a feather flock together". But said the phrase translated to "They cover themselves with the same blanket". Does anyone know what this phrase symbolizes in Spanish?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's an adaptation of:

> Cual la madre, tal la hija,
> y tal la manta que las cobija

*(Like the mother, like the daughter, and like the blanket that covers them)*

Which is actually more known for a popular (rude) version:

> Puta la madre, puta la hija,
> puta la manta que las cobija

*(Bitch the mother, bitch the daughter, bitch the blanket that covers them)*

Indicates the inheritance of habits, especially bad ones. It's used to indicate people who meet attracted by the same reason, especially if it's negative. Or people who develop the same pattern of behavior, usually negative.

Answer (score 2):

I also suspect that Danielillo's second proposal is what you are looking for.

I add these two expressions that have a similar meaning, that is, "both coincide in their negative characteristics":

> Cortados con la misma tijera.

> Dios los cría y el diablo los junta.

Comment: Interestingly, the first one (Cortados con la misma tijera) has a very close equivalent in English: "cut from the same cloth".

Answer (score 2):

Some equivalents in Spanish:

> Manta que cobija a la madre, cobija a la hija.

> Dos que duermen en el mismo colchón se vuelven de la misma opinión.

> Los que duermen bajo las mismas sábanas aprenden a hablar con la misma boca.

Answer (score 1):

En Español también tenemos un dicho, que no sé si puede ser concordante a lo que buscas y que dice:

**¡Quien a buen árbol se arrima, buena sombra le cobija!**

Ya que por lo visto la palabra "cobija" puede interpretarse como "cubrirse de, con", "blanketed by, of ".

[image]

[image]

Significado:

*"Es un refrán popular que se usa mucho en España. Se refiere a los beneficios que se pueden obtener de las buenas relaciones interpersonales, que es conveniente y ventajoso tener protectores poderosos".*

**Adhaerens potenti adversitatem non timet.**

*La expresión arriba mencionada se suele utilizar para indicar que si alguien va con gente buena, inteligente, trabajadora, hasta influyente (en el buen sentido de la palabra) tendrá un buen futuro, estará bien en la vida, las cosas le irán bien porque se deja influenciar por cosas positivas.*

---

*https://intercambio-hoorn.weebly.com/el-refraacuten-del-9-de-noviembre-de-2016--quieacuten-a-buen-aacuterbol-se-arrima-buena-sombra-le-cobija.html*

Comment: Me he permitido modificar el refrán, porque no era correcto. Lo tienes en *Refranero: Quien a buen árbol se arrima buena sombra le cobija*: https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=59342&Lng=0.

Comment: En cualquier caso: a mí me parece que no tiene el mismo sentido que el de la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias. No se, un pastor y que la sombra del árbol cubra a todos sus hijos en el cual están cobijados, me pareció igualmente que se podrían ayudar y seguir los sabios consejos...en fin, seguiré buscando algo que sirvan de "same blanket".